# Replacing the normal ActionBar by tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to create an app where the normal ActionBar is replaced by scrollable Tabs (like in Facebook Messenger)

[image]
Like the Image on the left side :)

How can I make something like that in Android Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: It is always better to attach the images rather than giving the URL. The url can break after some point of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these methods to hide the action bar title bar

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```